# Drupal 7 - Any module for storing profile as nodes?

Tags: users

I am currently using profile2 but I need to save the revisions too which is currently not possible in profile2.

Is there any other module or approach to achieve this?

Comment: me too profile2 revisions https://drupal.org/node/1043128